# Automatic typing password iphone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

In my UIViewController I have 2 textfields. One called passwordtextfield and the other retype. Instead of having people actually retype their passwords I want it to automatically fill it in. Is this possible? I tried something that keeps on crashing.

```
[_passwordtextfield addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


- (void)updateTextField:(id)sender{

    UITextField *retype =  ((UITextField *)_passwordtextfield).text;


    }
```

Comment: What is the point of having the field at all if you fill it in automatically?

Comment: If you are going to automatically fill it in, what is the point of having a 2nd field?

Comment: You're missing the entire point of having people type in their password twice.  The idea is to ensure that they didn't accidentally mistype it.  It would be terrible to think you're setting your password to one thing and (due to a typing error) actually set it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to cast your text field. You can assign direct value of your text field.So

Write this line

```
   retypetextfield.text =  _passwordtextfield.text;
```

instead of

```
UITextField *retype =  ((UITextField *)_passwordtextfield).text;
```

Comment: +1 for a functionally correct answer. -1 for not challenging the reason for the requirement.

Comment: hheehheh thanx dude...now i'll give reason

Comment: +1 on answer.  @Abizem would -1 if I could.  Functionally correct answer should not be judged badly due the the quality of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this, as mentioned in the comments, but to answer the question... It looks like you are creating a new `UITextField` in `updateTextField` instead of setting the text of one that exists. It should look something like this:

```
- (void)updateTextField:(id)sender{
    retypeFied.Text = _passwordtextfield.text;
}
```

Substitute whatever you named the pointer to your second field for `retypeField`.